# Press buttons and show text (and hide the previous text)

Tags: jquery

i have some buttons and i want when the user press them show some text and hide the text of the previous button. It seems simple but my code isnt working ( you can see it and here -> [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/qXEZQ/2/))

```
//These are the buttons
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class=" span1 offset0" target="1"> <a href="#" class="circle lnkCollapse">TITLE1</a></div>
    <div class="span1 offset4" target="2"> <a href="#" class="circle lnkCollapse">TITLE2</a></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="contentArea">
      <div class="box-title">TITLE:</div>

           //this is the text for the 1st button
           <div id="div1">
                <div class="box-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                 </div>           
                 <div class="box-links">
                       <a href="#">GO</a>
                       <a href="#">TEST</a> 
                  </div>
            </div>

           //this is the text for the 2nd button
           <div id="div2">
                <div class="box-text">
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                 </div>       
                 <div class="box-links">
                      <a href="#">GO</a>
                      <a href="#">TEST</a> 
                 </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

In the header i put this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.lnkCollapse').click(function () {
               $('.contentArea').hide();
               $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
         });
    });
```

and nothing happens.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems:

1. jQuery was not included in the fiddle
2. The `contentArea` element is the container, you should not hide that element, you need to hide the children inside it whose id starts with `div`
3. Again the `target` attribute is not present in the `lnkCollapse` element, it is in the parent element

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.lnkCollapse').click(function () {
        $('.contentArea div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div' + $(this).parent().attr('target')).show();
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RnJbu/)

**How it should be done**

```
//use data-target attribute with the complete target selector
<div class="span1 offset0" data-target="#div1"> <a href="#" class="circle lnkCollapse "> <h3> title 1 </h3></a>
```

then

```
//add a class content to all target div elements to group them
<div class="content" id="div1">
    .....
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $contents = $('.contentArea .content');
    $('.lnkCollapse').click(function () {
        $contents.hide();
        $($(this).parent().data('target')).show();
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YGUpg/)

Comment: +1 But I'd suggest using `data` attributes instead of regular attributes and contain the entire ID their not only a number

Answer (score 1):

Try it (Your parentNode div is hiding all his child, take this child node with buttons
 up by DOM):

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="contentArea">
      <div class="box-title">TITLE:</div>

           //this is the text for the 1st button
           <div id="div1">
                <div class="box-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                 </div>           
                 <div class="box-links">
                       <a href="#">GO</a>
                       <a href="#">TEST</a> 
                  </div>
            </div>

           //this is the text for the 2nd button

</div>
<--------- End Container for close

<div id="div2">
                <div class="box-text">
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                 </div>       
                 <div class="box-links">
                      <a href="#">GO</a>
                      <a href="#">TEST</a> 
                 </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**use HTML5 data attribute to use custom attributes**.. this is why data attr was introduces in html5..

try this

**html**

```
 ...
 <div class="span1 offset0" data-target="1"> <a href="#" class="circle lnkCollapse"> <h3> title 1 </h3></a>
...
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
 $('.lnkCollapse').click(function () {
   $('[id^="div"]').hide(); //<--- hide all div starting with id as div
   $('#div' + $(this).parent().data('target')).show();
 });
});
```

hide all divs whose id is stratin with `div` and not the parent element (parent div).

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/qXEZQ/4/)